# How do I match a value in multiple rows in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing

I have a csv file that contains

| Full Name | Some Column | Access Required |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith | Stuff | System 1 |
| John Smith | something | System 3 |
| Bob Villa | other | Application 4 |
| Bob Villa | more | Application 6 |
| Doug Mack | stuff | System 2 |

I'd like to import this csv and match based upon one "full name" at a time (that I'm getting from a variable ie:Full Name) so that I get an out which I'll send as the body of an email that is:

Full Name: John Smith
Access Required: System 1
Access Required: System 3

Then I will run script again looking for Bob Villa and get:
Full Name: Bob Villa
Access Required: Application 4
Access Required: Application 6

I think I could do this with a bunch of "if statements" but I'm wondering if there's a way to parse the csv based upon "full name" and then list all the entries found in the "Access Required" column for each row that "full name" is found?

Note: I don't want anything from any other columns (and there could be lots of them), just want the contents of "Access Required"

Thank you!

Comment: Is the _order_ important? If the first line has John Smith, the next one has Bob Villa, and the last one has John Smith _again_, should John Smith get 2 separate emails?

Comment: This is initiated by a separate process. So it will be import entire CSV each time but look for a single name at a time. ie: import csv look for user who could be "Bob Villa" then put the Full Name: Bob VIlla and the Access Required lines into the body of the email.  Then on a subsequent run, import csv and look for different name and list access requires...

Comment: That's _one way_ of doing it, I'm asking whether it's _important_ to do it like that? :-)

Comment: Hopefully I'm understanding your question but yes. It's important to do it that way due to the initiating process that starts this.  It will read a value of full name then go build an AD account.  Then it writes the samAccountName back into this vile but it also then needs to list all of the access requirements for that full name as variables or something to send off an email each time an account is created.   It's a strange process but like I said, it will read one full name at a time, take action, then read another, take more, rinse & repeat.

Comment: Order of rows not important but John Smith should only get one email listing the all the access requirements found in that column.

Answer (score 3):

Import the csv in a variable and select the data for the user by the full name:

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path 'path\to\input.csv'
# example select John Smith

$user = 'John Smith'
$selection = $data | Where-Object {$_.'Full Name' -eq $user}
if (@($selection).Count) {
    # format as you like, for simplicity
    $table = $selection | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String
    # in a html mail embed $table inside '<pre>' tags, so
    # it will display in a monospace font.
    # $body = "<pre>$table</pre>"
}
else {
    Write-Warning "Could not find $user"
}
```

Just import once, keep variable $data and repeat the part that starts with `$user = ...` for each new user

Comment: Thank you for this!   My mistake as I forgot to mention there are many columns of unknown amounts or content.  I'm only interested in the values in "Access Required".  Your above script lists all columns (my mistake) but it also lists John Smith twice, not just once...like my sample output.

Appreciated though!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue using a combination of Foreach, an if statment and then switch.

```
    $source = '\somesoure.csv'
    $csv = import-csv $source
    Foreach($row in $csv){
    $personName = $row."Full Name"
    $accessRequired = $row."Access Required"

    if ($personName -eq $mayInputNameVariable){
    //do some code stuff such as write to a column

    switch ($accessRequired){

    "System 1" {
    $System1 = "Access Required: System 1`n" 
    }

    //do it for all switch values
     }
    $emailBody = "Full Name:$personName`n" + $system1 + $system2 ...etc

    $csv | Export-CSV $source -NoTypeInformation
```

Thanks folks!